# PHP file upload to directory based upon unique user id

Tags: php, file, variables, upload, directory

I can't seem to get the directory to take the user **id variable ($id)** in the file path. Uploading straight into the member folder is no issue, but once I try for the unique folder created based upon user id during registration, I am roadblocked.

Here is what I've pieced together thus far:

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$udir= "members/.$id./";
$ufile = $udir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$allexts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($ext, $allexts)){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $ufile)) {
        echo "File upload was successful.";
    } else {
        echo "An error has occured. Please try again.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file type. Please try again.";
} ?>
```

Comment: Your `$udir` comes out to be a dot-folder.

Comment: @arxanas yeah, i've tried with and without the concatenation periods to no avail.

Comment: Except the way you have it written, they're not being used as concatenation periods, they're just part of the string.  You have to close the string first before you can use the `.` operator.

Comment: @Crontab that was the issue. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(!is_dir($udir)){

    mkdir("members/".$id, 0777);
}
```

your code:-

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$udir= "members/".$id."/";

if(!is_dir($udir)){

    mkdir("members/".$id, 0777);
}

$ufile = $udir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$allexts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($ext, $allexts)){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $ufile)) {
        echo "File upload was successful.";
    } else {
        echo "An error has occured. Please try again.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file type. Please try again.";
}
```

Comment: the directory is already made, but my syntax was obviously wrong. thank you for correcting it.